# Nodejs router app crashes because of export

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, export, backend

I was practicing an online tutorial on Expressjs.  But now I dont' know why nodejs app crashes whenever i run "npm start" on the terminal  and shows error. I think the reason of error is related to export import but can't figure out how to solve this. Here is the [github repository link](https://github.com/shahab570/nodejs-router) . Please help me to fix this bug

Comment: remove `exports.routes = router;` & `exports.products = products;` this from admin.js file and add `module.exports = router` because there is no any module called product in your admin.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working for me. Either you haven't installed nodemon or have forgot to install node modules.

Run "npm install" command to download node_modules/ and then run "npm start"

If it still gives error, you have not installed nodemon

run "npm install --save nodemon -g" command

This will install nodemon globally so you need not install it for other projects. It also saves the module in this project.

Open package.json file. In scripts it says "npm start" means "nodemon app.js"

Nodemon keeps running the app while you run code.

If you dont like it, you can also run "node app.js"

Comment: I forgot to install node modules. Problem is solved. Thank you so much